# Mobilesync>Backup eating up Disk space

Tags: itunes, backup, disk-space

My PC is always recently showing low disk space despite me eliminating files.  I ran Tree size and discovered large volume from iTunes sync backup.  Before deleting in iTunes>preference, May I just copy/paste this directory

> *C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup*

to another drive first and in case I need to restore, I can copy it back to that directory and restore in iTunes?  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. So long as you keep the structure intact you can move it elsewhere for safe keeping.

You could also trim it to only the most recent backup if you wished.

If your backups are encrypted, the only way to identify is by the date of each folder, otherwise the date should be in each folder title.